# Determine whether $f(x)=1+x,g(x)=1+|x|$ are linearly independent on the real line

Tags: calculus

I have conceptual confusions. First off we compute the Wronskian:

$$W(f,g)= \bigg|\matrix{1+x && 1+|x| \\ 1 && \text{sgn}(x)}\bigg| = (1+x)\text{sgn}(x)-1-|x| = \cases{-2 & x<0 \\ -1 & x=0 \\ 0 & x>0}$$

However, there's a lot of handwaving here: $g$ is not differentiable at $x=0$, so $W$ should be understood relative to either $(-\infty,0)$ or $(0,\infty)$. In the first case $W$ is never zero, so $f,g$ are l.i. there; in the second case $W$ identically zero, so $f,g$ are l.d. there.

But computing the Wronskian should only make sense when $f,g$ are both differentiable, right? In this case we could just argue that $f \neq kg, k\in \mathbb{R}$ because differentiability is closed under scalar multiplication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the Wronskian is only for differentiable functions.

Second, even if both functions are continuously differentiable the vanishing of the Wronskian does **not** imply linear dependence (Peano's example: $x^2$ and $x |x|$).

Third, I don't know why some textbooks make such a big deal about the Wronskian for two functions.  In most cases, it's blatantly obvious whether one function
is a scalar multiple of the other (in the rare cases where this
depends on some tricky identity, that identity is likely to affect the Wronskian as well).

Comment: My textbook says the following: suppose $y_1,y_2$ are solutions of the homogeneous second-order linear equation $y''+p(x)y'+q(x)y=0$ on an open interval $I$ in which $p,q$ are continuous. Then if $y_1,y_2$ are linearly independent, then $W(y_1,y_2)\neq 0$ at all points in $I$. Does this mean that $x^2,x|x|$ cannot be both solutions to a homogeneous second-order linear differential equation?

Comment: Yes, it does (if the interval contains $0$).  Of course $x |x|$ can't be a solution to a second-order differential equation, because it is not twice differentiable at $0$.

Answer (score 0):

You can sidestep the awkwardness by only using the Wronskian on the bad side. If two functions are linearly independent on a subset, they cannot be linearly dependent on the whole space.

Your second argument is correct.

A similar direct argument- suppose $f=kg$. Then as $f(x)=g(x)$ for $x>0$, we must have $k=1$. But then for e.g. $x=-1$, we note that $f(-1) = 0 \neq g(-1) = 2$, so there can be no such $k$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $$c_1(1+x)+c_2 (1+|x|)=0$$

You need to show that $$c_1=c_2=0$$

Let $x=0$, and you get $$c_1+c_2=0$$

Let $x=-1$ and you get $2c_2 =0$ thus both $c_1$ and $c_2=0$

Thus they are linearly independent.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the definition of linear independence. Two functions $f$ and $g$ are linearly independent iff the only solution to the equation $af + bg=0,$ where $a$ and $b$ are constants, is $a=b=0.$ This is easy to generalize. The functions $f_1,f_2,...,f_n$ are linearly independent iff the only solution to $c_1f_1 + c_2f_2+\dots+c_nf_n$ is the trivial $c_1=c_2=\dots=c_n=0.$

In your case, it is easy to show that this is the case by considering various values of the functions (e.g. when $x\ge0$, $f(x)=g(x)$ and when $x=-1,$ $f(x)=0$ and $g(x)=2$). This is very similar to the notion of linear independence for vectors.